# SpringBoot GraphQL mutation giving error No Root resolvers for query type 'Query' found

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, mutation

Am getting the error **No Root resolvers for query type 'Query' found** when using mutation in SpringBoot with GraphQL. The queries are working fine , but on adding the GraphQLMutationResolver, it is giving the error on Spring Boot startup.

Kindly advise.

**.graphqls file**

```
type Query {
    allBooks: [Book]
    getBookByIsn(isn: Int): Book
    allPublishers: [Publisher]
}

type Book {
    isn: Int
    title: String
    author: String
    publishedDate: String
    publisher: Publisher!
}

type Publisher {
    pId : Int
    publisherName: String
    address: String
}

input CreatePublisher {
    pId : Int
    publisherName: String
    address: String
}


type Mutation {
    addPublisher(input: CreatePublisher!): Publisher
}
```

**Mutation Resolver**

```
@Component
public class PublisherMutation implements GraphQLMutationResolver{
    
    @Autowired
    private PublisherRepository publisherRepository;
    
    @Transactional
    public Publisher addPublisher(CreatePublisher createPublisher ) {
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher(createPublisher.getPId(), createPublisher.getPublisherName(), createPublisher.getAddress());
        publisherRepository.save(publisher);
        return publisher;
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Done, solved by adding a `newTypeWiring` of type Mutation for Create

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).